# My text isn't showing in the python Shell. Help! Uses Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Please help! It comes up with an error saying that there is a missing "Self" and I cant find it. I have tried everything and i cant find the error.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter    


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = tkinter.Tk()
        self.master.title("Encrypter & Decrypter")

        def E_Entry(self):
            print(self.E_Entry.get(self))

        self.E_Question = Label(self.master, text="Encrypter",)
        self.E_Question.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)

        self.E_Entry = Entry(self.master, width = 25)
        self.E_Entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.E_Button = Button(self.master, text="Encrypt", command=E_Entry)
        self.E_Button.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.D_Question = Label(self.master, text="Decrypter",)
        self.D_Question.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

        self.D_Entry = Entry(self.master, width = 25)
        self.D_Entry.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.D_Button = Button(self.master, text="Decrypt")
        self.D_Button.grid(row=2, column=3)            


        self.master.mainloop()



App()
```

Comment: I ran your program and didn't see any errors. Am I supposed to do something with these buttons and text boxes? You should provide enough detail in your question so that other people can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a function with the same name as the widget, the indentation of the function is incorrect, and you are calling it incorrectly.

It should be something like this:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.E_Button = Button(..., command=self.print_e)
        ...

    def print_e(self):
        print(self.E_Entry.get())
```

Comment: I have tried editing it to how you have it and now nothing happens when I run the program. Should i comment what i have done? @Bryan Oakley

Comment: No one can guess what your code is now.  You will have to post it to get help.

Answer (score 0):

On the line where it says:

```
App()
```

You should have assigned the resulting object to a variable, such as:

```
my_app = App()
```